# IdentityServer4 with User Administration system need to be impelemented in ASP.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using identityServer4 for first time and I need some help with the implementing in my asp.net core project. I have many applications asp.net core based and their user system must be managed by common server, because they have not same orgin (http://ip:prot1 and http://ip:port2).
i can so far implement an idetntyServer4 to make client cridential authentication. Now i just can't know what is the correct process flow to get the user data back to my applications.

From Website A click on login --> login ( should happen in identityServer4?) --> then when successful --> redirect to the sending page (website A)--- the logged user data must be send back .. how it happens?
now i click from website a --> b --> what should happen? how i get the user data, that my system know?

another question, why should the identityserver need a user store? will be the login data in this database saved? it is not just cookies based?

the last question: where should i put the api of user query from my db? in identityServer4?

the documentation is not quiet helpful as they did't show the process flow.

Do you know any quickstart for the identityServer not mvc based (just razor pages). it could be more simpler than their mvc quickstarts

Hope i find some help here :)

Answer (score 1):

QuickStart is an example of protecting api. When Website A click on login, it should happen in identityServer4. After logining successfully, it will send the token to Website A, then Website A can access the api with the token.

About the logged user data and user store, you need to configure the database on identityserver, and use identity to deal with the logged user. When user login successfully, it can save the user infomation in a cookie, you can retrieve the user info from the cookie.

About user query, if it is about the authentication, you need to put them on the identityserver. Otherwise, it should be put on the api.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. that helped alot. I wanna ask you then, how could i get the current user info in the client? you said i can get the user info from the cookies, you mean in server right? I need to get it the client. I just could query the user-id in my client with code:

`var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;`

However, the defined claims in server i could not either get them in client, do you know how i could query them there?
thank you in advanced